# Send data from React to Node js

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to send data from React to Node js. I'm using Ajax. I don't get data by Node.js

This is my code on React :

let id = item.id

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/postid',
            type: 'POST',
            data: id

        });
        console.log('React id  : ' + id);
```

And my code on Node.js

```
app.post('/postid', function (req, res) {

        console.log("node js ok");
        var getId = req.body.id; // here, i don't get the id value
        console.log("id Node js : " + getId);       
    });
```

Do you have an idea ? 
Thank you

Comment: The id is a string i suppose?

Comment: yes it's a string

Comment: Try the answer I gave.

Comment: Have you used `body-parser` at node js server?

Comment: No .. I'm not using body parser

Comment: so..... use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this at the frontend:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/postid',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify({ id: 'id here' })
});
```

Use `body-parser` at the node js server otherwise, you will not be able to get parameters from the request body.

Comment: You're right , i import body-parser, and it works , thank you :) !

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use more modern approach like [**FetchAPI**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).
Use it with [Polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch), because it is not fully supported in all the browsers. With **fetch** your code will look like this:

```
fetch('/postid', {
  method: 'POST',
  // headers: {} <-- You can include some headers if you want
  body: JSON.stringify({id: id})

}).then(function(response) {
   return response.json();

}).then(function(json) {
  // json -> is your response from server

}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle errors here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/postid',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"id": id}

    });
    console.log('React id  : ' + id);
```

Comment: it doesn't work .. I have an error on node console : "cannot read property id of undefined "

Comment: Do you have bodyparser and cors in you express app

Comment: I did'nt have bodyparser, i import it and it works, thank you :)